# Why doesn't my message.reply command not work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My bot has connected to the server, it becomes online when I start the code, but i can't seem to figure out why the message.reply command doesnt work

Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('Message', (message) => {

    if(message.content == 'ping') {

        message.reply('pong');
    }

});
```

Am i missing something? i'm coding using visual studio code

Comment: Did you try the event name "message" in lowercase?

Answer (score 3):

Client's events are case-sensitive, therefore, "Message" and "message" are completely two different things.

Replace "Message" with "message" on line 5 to fix your code.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content == 'ping') {
        message.reply('pong');
    }
});
```